# Lower than usual screen resolution on MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display

My MacBook Pro screen has a lower than usual screen resolution. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out someone has just messed around with my System Preferences.
Going to `System Preferences` >> `Displays` >> `Display` >> `Resolution` and changing it to `Default for display` did the trick.

Comment: It is good practice to set up a guest account if you allow others access to your Mac and password on wake. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one display, additional resolution options are available.

After the display is connected, choose Apple menu > System Preferences, click Displays, then click Display. Press the Option key while you click Scaled to see additional resolutions for the second display.

macOS Sierra: Adjust your display's resolution - Apple Support
https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25175